# Unity 2D Collision Ignored When Applying High Speed Following One Target

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

My Game Basically Is about multiple player objects that follow the mouse position and have `CircleCollider` component each but when the players are so close from each other they do not collide and begin to coincide.

Is there a way to detect `GameObject` in front of each player so its speed will be zero and if the player has empty sight It can move straight forward?

> I think it could be achieved by getting the first contact in the up vector of the player and comparing the tag of the `GameObject` then if it is `Player` the self speed is set to zero.

Comment: Is your object set to Continuous or Discrete physics?

Comment: @Draco18s it is set to Discrete why?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your objects use the `RigidBody2D` component, you could try changing the collision detection mode from "Discrete" to "Continuous".

To stop the objects from pushing each other, put this code before the code that moves the object:

```
    Vector2 difference = target - (Vector2)transform.position;
    RaycastHit2D[] hit = new RaycastHit2D[1];
    if (Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, radius, difference.normalized, new ContactFilter2D(), hit, difference.magnitude) > 0) {
        // Something is in the way
        float firstObstacleDistance = hit[0].distance;
        target = difference.normalized * firstObstacleDistance;
    }
```

The variable `target` should be the mouse position and `radius` is the radius of the `CircleCollider` component.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: I believe "Discrete" checks for collision on every `FixedUpdate`, but "Continuous" makes sure to check the points between. Lets say you had an object going 100 units every second, which is 2 units every `FixedUpdate`. If both objects are 1 unit wide, then it's possible for it to go from the left of the object to the right of the object. If it's "Continuous", then it would check whether there is an object between where it starts and ends on each `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: Ok Thanks I switched to `Continous` Mode But there is one problem left When the players are following the mouse position they seem fight to reach their target the players collide hardly is there a way to smoothen the movement if they can't reach their target? I made a 2D Physics Material with friction = 0.But it didn't work perfectly.It kept lagging.

Comment: Hopefully the (untested) code in my updated answer should work.
Before the code, `target` should be set to the mouse position and `radius` is set to the circle's radius.